# Error: The getter 'isWindows' isn't defined for the type 'Platform'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi I want to ask if I use dart html is Platform.isWindows not usable. Can anyone explain to me. How do I solve this problem?

Code:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io' as io;

    Future startFilePicker(String fileNotes, BuildContext context) async {
      List<int> selectedFile;
      Uint8List bytesData;
      String selectedDocumentName = "Unspecified";
      File selectedDocument;
    
      FilePickerResult? result;
      if (Platform.isWindows) {
        if (fileNotes.toLowerCase() == 'photos') {
          result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.media);
        } else if (fileNotes.toLowerCase() == 'radiology') {
          result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(type: FileType.media);
        } else {
          result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
        }
      } else {
        result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles();
      }
    
      if (result != null) {
        PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
        selectedDocument = File(file.path);
        selectedDocumentName = file.name;
        selectedFile = [];
        bytesData = await selectedDocument.readAsBytes();
        selectedFile = bytesData;
        await uploadFile(selectedDocument, selectedFile, context, fileNotes,
            selectedDocumentName, selectedDocumentName);
      }
    }
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using prefix on import. it will be

```dart
  import 'dart:io' as io;
  if ( io.Platform.isWindows) {
```